# Java objects and constructors/methods

Tags: java

The best way for me to explain what I am trying to get this code to do is by copying and pasting the assignment that ive been given.

I have coded the thing myself however the problem I am having is two variables seem to not be adding up at all but when I test the code it still works.

The two variables I am trying to get to add up are storePower and strength

Create a class to represent a Superhero. Every Superhero has a name. Every Superhero can also have a strength, but this should be optional. If a Superhero does not have a strength, their default strength should be 10.

Every Superhero can receive a powerUp, whereby their strength is increased by a speciﬁed amount

public class Superhero{

```
//private instance variables declared below.

//name of the super hero
private String name;
//name of power up variable
private int powerUp;
//name of the strength variable
private int strength;
private int storePower;







/*
Power ups work in a way that if the powerUp is greater then or equal to 10 then add 5 to strength
if the powerUp is greater than  or equal to 5 then add 2 to the strength
if it is less than 5 then add 1 to the strength.
*/

public void powerUp(int powerUp){
this.powerUp = powerUp;
    if(powerUp >= 10){
        storePower = 5;
        strength = storePower + strength;
        //this system out was to test if this bit of code is working.
        System.out.println("Power up is set to 10 or higher!" + " The power is: " + strength);
    }else if(powerUp >= 5){
        storePower = 2;
        strength = storePower + strength;
    }else if (powerUp < 5){
        storePower = 1;
        strength = storePower + strength;
    }else{
        System.out.println("Something is not right..");
    }


}

//constructor for if the player wanted to specify the name and the strength
public Superhero(String name, int strength){
    this.name = name;
    this.strength = strength;

    System.out.println(name + " " + strength);
}



//if the user doesn't enter the strength as it is optional
//this constructor below will run and set the default
public Superhero(String name){
    this.name = name;
    this.strength = 10 + storePower;
    System.out.println(name + " " + strength );
}
```

}
Fight class below

```
public class Fight{
public static void main(String[] args){

    //creating a new instance of the Superhero object
    Superhero cyclops = new Superhero("cyclops");



    cyclops.powerUp(10);
}
```

}

The output when ran on the command line is:

> cyclops 10
>   Power up is set to 10 or higher! The power is: 5

The output I am trying to get is 15 because the power up is set to higher than 10 therefore the if statement sets it to 5, however I cannot get these to add up

Comment: _I cannot get these to add up_ is not a question. Why can't you get them to add up? What did your debugging show?

Comment: I have tried adding the two variables together however it didn't work

Comment: this.strength = strength + storePower;

Comment: You set `storePower` to `5`, then you print `storePower` and it is `5`.  You haven't changed the value, so why would you expect anything else?

Comment: because storePower is added onto the strength variable?

Comment: however it does not get added on

Comment: public Superhero(String name){
  this.name = name;
  
  this.strength = 10 + storePower;
  
  System.out.println(name + " " + (strength + storePower));
 }

Comment: where its printed cyclops 10 it should have 15 because the two variables just aren't adding

Comment: No. you are only doing that in the constructor. The `powerUp` method only makes an assignment, no additions.

Comment: I agree, you don't have clear question, simplify and make it more exposed

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like this

```
public void powerUp(int powerUp){
this.powerUp = powerUp;
    if(powerUp >= 10){
        storePower = 5;
          strength  = storePower+powerUp
        //this system out was to test if this bit of code is working.
        System.out.println("Power up is set to 10 or higher!" + " The power is: " + strength  );
    }else if(powerUp >= 5 & powerUp <10){
        storePower = 2;
        strength  =  powerUp+StorePower
 System.out.println("Power up is set to 5 or greater but less than 10!" + " The power is: " + strength  );
    }else if (powerUp < 5){
        storePower = 1;
        Strength  = storePower + powerUp;
 System.out.println("Power up is set to less than 5!" + " The power is: " + strength  );
    }else{
        System.out.println("Something is not right..");
    }

}
```

Comment: That code brought up quite a few errors couldn't get it to work

Comment: even after fixing the errors it still keeps cyclops at 10

Comment: Can you please tell us exactly what output do you want ? , This code should print . Power Up is Set to 10 or Higher! The power is 15